# Layout with 3 columns with equal width doesn't render equally with Opera and Safari

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have a pretty straightforward page with a wrapper which contains 3 seciotns (float: left; width: 33.333%).

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row{
    width: 100%;
    _height: expression(this.height > 384 ? 384: true);
    max-height: 384px;  
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}  
.row:after
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.row .column{
    float: left;    
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
} 
.row .column .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now I have them work perfectly with all browser except for Safari and Opera, after searching stack overflow and google a lot I found a couple of similar question without a real working solution...one guy was suggesting to have the third column float right and be 34% wide, while col one and two were 33% but that didn't worked out..there's still a super tiny pixel on the 
right..

So basically it appears to be a rounding issue, I read about it a lot, but since I can't change the disign i was looking for a work around...

Mi current solution is to avoid fluid design on safari/opera...but I'm definitely not proud of that..

Here I trew html + css real quick:
http://jsfiddle.net/ventie30/N9SFJ/

Just to give you a few more info I have 3 rows and 3 columns, rows are separated by 40px.

Comment: Quick note: your fiddle is linking to password-protected files.

Comment: mmm...strange, I think I can see it...(meaning I jsut opened the link on another browser where I'm not logged in)

Comment: same issue here in safari. still a year later.